Displaying the time in react using use effect
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Child() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date());
    }, 1000);

  }, []);

  return <p>The current time is: {time.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>;
}
export default Child;


I was not able to understand how the time is changing every second as we know i have given the dependencies as an empty array it should be updated only once but updated every second but how can you explain , So can anyone explain how does the code work

Because your set up a timer by using setInterval, the time state will be updated every second. Please clarify what do you want to achieve.

i mean to say when we use useeffect with empty array dependency the rendering is done only once right? but how do the setInterval is being called every time

Yes. The effect function passed into useEffect is called only once with empty dependency list. But the callback of setInterval will be called every second.

useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTime(new Date());
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [time]);

        <p className='m-5'>The current time is:{time.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')}</p>;

The time is continuously changed that's why time is in useEffect dependency...
When Calling the setinterval in one sec it must be clear old-one

Thank You Dude this had already worked for me

This is the steps which occurs:

Initialization:


First your Child component gets created.
time state is initialized with the current date object.
a timer running at a interval of 1000 sec is registered with a callback function.
The time state value is shown with its initial value.


After each timer interval when callback runs


Callback calls the setTime useState hook updater function.
The time state gets updated with a new date-time which triggers a re-render and gets updated with the new time value.


Additionally, you should write a cleanup function for your setInterval. Otherwise, there will be a memory leak if its missed.
useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTime(new Date());
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

